# Is it possible to connect to a site through a proxy and then disconnect in the same session?

Tags: proxy

I was wondering if it is possible to log into a site with the normal login form (take facebook for example) through a proxy server.  Once logged in, can a person disconnect from the proxy and use their normal ISP connection to access the members area on the site without logging in again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the site manages state. If sessions are tied to a particular remote host, then no. Otherwise, there's nothing preventing it. Typically a session is managed via cookies or something similar that the browser sends with every request. Thus whether or not the proxy is there is irrelevant to the maintenance of the session state.